# Typescript nested interface throwing error

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two interfaces:

```
interface BarItem {
  planned: number;
  off: number;
  in: number;
  gdp_start: number;
  out: number;
  allocated: number;
}

interface BarData {
  max: number;
  title: string;
  tooltip: boolean;
  breaker: boolean;
  start_time: number;
  data: BarItem;
  linedata: number[];
}
```

This throws the following error on build:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/timeline-bar-graph/timeline-bar-graph.component.spec.ts(19,5): error TS2322: Type '{ max: number; title: string; tooltip: true; breaker: true; start_time: number; data: undefined[]...' is not assignable to type 'BarData'.
  Property 'linedata' is missing in type '{ max: number; title: string; tooltip: true; breaker: true; start_time: number; data: undefined[]...'.
```

Comment: add you'r code where you are using these interfaces. maybe its something with your initialization

Comment: add safe traversal to skip the error

Comment: The error is specifically telling you that `linedata` is missing, it has nothing to do with nested interfaces. In other words, `linedata` is **required** when creating a `BarData` but not being set in a `BarData` created in timeline-bar-graph.component.spec.ts. Either give that `BarData` a `linedata` (can be `null`), or mark `linedata` as optional (`linedata?: number[];`).